# How to follow-up after doing a bad job on a "role play" interview question for grad school admissions?

Tags: graduate-school

I recently interviewed for a very competitive clinical mental health counseling Masters program(didn't know how competitive until the day of the interview). During the interview we were asked to role play a quick counseling session. Channeling all the confidence I had, I went first. Big mistake. I didn't do what I needed to in terms of empathizing, I mainly asked questions to gain more knowledge on the clients situation before the interviewer quickly ended my turn. I got through the rest of the interview feeling good about my answers. It's been about a week since the interview, I sent out thank you letters a few days after the fact. Now I have a coworker who went to the school (different program) insisting that I ask for a second chance. I don't think I want to do that, but is there any way that I can still email them addressing the situation? It is a very close knit relationship centered program, which my coworker pointed out, and they are trained counselors. 
I've been reading other experiences where after a bad interview people emailed asking for feedback, or addressing things they wish went differently. Is it too late since I sent out the thank you letters? Not sure of what my next move should be. Thanks in advance.

I spoke to another candidate who is close with the current students and he said they were specifically looking for the candidate to show empathy - which I know I didn't do well enough.